# socket.io-client vs socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

What's the difference between [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) and [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) ?

I also find a bit confusing that socket.io-client also has a section for ["server-side usage"](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client#nodejs-server-side-usage)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`socket-io.client` is the code for the client-side implementation of socket.io.  That code may be used either by a browser client or by a server process that is initiating a socket.io connection to some other server (thus playing the client-side role in a socket.io connection).

A server that is not initiating socket.io connections to other servers would not use this code.  This has been made a little more confusing that it probably should be because when using socket.io, it appears that both client and server are using the same `socket.io.js` file (because they both refer to a file with the same name), but is not actually the case.  The server is using a different file than the client.

From the [Github page for socket-io.client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client):

> A standalone build of socket.io-client is exposed automatically by the
>   socket.io server as /socket.io/socket.io.js. Alternatively you can
>   serve the file socket.io.js found at the root of this repository.

Keep in mind that there are unique features that belong to client and server so it should not be a surprise that they use some different code.  Though they share code for parsing the protocol and things like that, the server has the ability to run a server or hook into an existing web server and it has methods like `.join()` and `.leave()` and data structures that keep track of all the connected sockets and is expected to live in the node.js environment.  The client has the ability to initiate a connection (send the right http request), do polling if webSockets are not supported, build on a native webSocket implementation if present, etc....

Comment: Would you elaborate when is it used on the server-side e.g Node.js? In other words what is the scenario when we want to have it on the server-side rather browser?

Comment: @ShahinGhasemi - You use socket-io.client in your server when your server is initiating a socket.io connection to some other server socket.io server.

Comment: so if I'm using socketIO in flask (backend) and socket.io-client in react (on node.js) is it correct ?

Comment: @Qbik - Sorry, but I don't know flask or any of its libraries.