# What is the difference between flutter socket-io and socket-io-client?

Tags: flutter, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to figure out what should I use in flutter whether socket-io or socket-io-client? I am pretty confused. I saw this post
[socekt-io vs socekt-io-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041583/socket-io-client-vs-socket-io), but I didn't get enough clarity. I am using flask-socketio in backend. So what do I prefer in flutter, socket-io or socket-io-client? I see many examples online using socket-io, so shall I use socket-io too in flutter? also I wanted to know once the socket-io connection is done, does socket-io automatically display chat screen or we have to make the ui and call socket-io methods?

Answer (score 0):

socket.io module is used in server side while socket.io-client in front (To establish connection with server side) . For the chat you have To create it manually socket.io just offer you a persistent connection for many requests instead of using à connection for each request( like http).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Socket.IO and Socket.IO Client are both libraries that enable real-time communication between a Flutter application and a Socket.IO server. However, they are designed for different use cases and have some differences in their implementation.

**Flutter Socket.IO:**

- Flutter Socket.IO is a Flutter-specific implementation of the
  Socket.IO protocol. It provides a high-level API and integrates
  seamlessly with Flutter applications.
- It is built on top of the Dart programming language and provides a
  set of classes and methods for handling Socket.IO connections,
  sending and receiving messages, and managing events.
- Flutter Socket.IO allows bidirectional communication between the
  client (Flutter app) and the server, enabling real-time data
  exchange. This library is maintained by the Flutter community and is
  designed to work specifically with Flutter applications.

**Socket.IO Client:**

- Socket.IO Client is a general-purpose client library for Socket.IO
  that can be used with various programming languages, including Dart
  (which Flutter uses).
- It provides a lower-level API and allows developers to establish
  connections with Socket.IO servers and exchange messages. Socket.IO
  Client is not Flutter-specific but can be used in any Dart
  application, including Flutter.
- It offers more flexibility and control compared to Flutter Socket.IO
  but requires additional configuration and setup.

In summary, Flutter Socket.IO is a Flutter-specific implementation of Socket.IO, providing a higher-level API tailored for Flutter applications. On the other hand, Socket.IO Client is a more general-purpose client library that can be used with Dart, including Flutter, but requires more manual configuration. The choice between them depends on your specific needs and preferences.

you should definitely go for socket.io and you have to make a ui call or listen for an event with socket.io to display chat screen

Comment: This content is most likely generated by an AI. Please read Stack Overflow's guide on AI content.

Comment: If it is not generated by AI, please cite your sources.